# 'paypal' is not defined in PHP

Tags: php, paypal

I have codes in ajax which calls php file to show the paypal sdk button in that page :

```js
function redirectPaypal() {
    $('#tabs2').html('<img src="' + webroot + 'facebox/loading.gif">');
    callAjax(webroot + 'TESTS.php', 'mode=paypall', function (t) {
        //  $.facebox(t);
        $('#walletBg').removeClass('addBgColor');
        $('#paypalBg').addClass('addBgColor');
        $('#neverBg').removeClass('addBgColor');
        $('#authBg').removeClass('addBgColor');
        // $('#paymentInfo').show();     
        $('#tabs2').html(t);
    });
}
```

As you see it calls TESTS.php file with the mode value `paypal`. The TESTS.php file is looks like below :

```php-template
<? 
require_once 'application-top.php';
require_once 'includes/navigation-functions.php';
require_once 'includes/site-functions-extended.php';
require_once 'includes/buy-deal-functions.php';
// ini_set('display_errors', 1);
// ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
// error_reporting(E_ALL);
$post = getPostedData();
print_r($post);
if ($_POST['mode'] == 'paypall')
{ 
    ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Add meta tags for mobile and IE -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <title> PayPal Checkout Integration | Client Demo </title>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Set up a container element for the button -->
    <div id="paypal-button-container"></div>
    <!-- Include the PayPal JavaScript SDK -->
    <script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=test&currency=USD" data-namespace="paypal_sdk"></script>
    <script>
        // Render the PayPal button into #paypal-button-container
        paypal_sdk.Buttons({
            // Set up the transaction
            createOrder: function(data, actions) {
                return actions.order.create({
                    purchase_units: [{
                        amount: {
                            value: '88.44'
                        }
                    }]
                });
            },
            // Finalize the transaction
            onApprove: function(data, actions) {
                return actions.order.capture().then(function(orderData) {
                    // Successful capture! For demo purposes:
                    console.log('Capture result', orderData, JSON.stringify(orderData, null, 2));
                    var transaction = orderData.purchase_units[0].payments.captures[0];
                    alert('Transaction '+ transaction.status + ': ' + transaction.id + '\n\nSee console for all available details');

                    // Replace the above to show a success message within this page, e.g.
                    // const element = document.getElementById('paypal-button-container');
                    // element.innerHTML = '';
                    // element.innerHTML = '<h3>Thank you for your payment!</h3>';
                    // Or go to another URL:  actions.redirect('thank_you.html');
                });
            }
        }).render('#paypal-button-container');
    </script>
</body>
</html>
<?
} 
?>
```

File is called successfully but as you see the code below I am getting the reference error when the page is called :

```
VM1597:3 
        
       Uncaught ReferenceError: paypal_sdk is not defined
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (js.php?f=js%2Fjquery-1.7.2.min.js%2Cjs%2Fmodernizr.custom.02358.js%2Cfunctions.js.php%2Cjs%2Fsite-functions.js%2Cform-validation.js.php%2Cform-validation-lang.php%2Cjs%2Fjquery-ui.min.js%2Cfacebox%2Ffacebox.js%2Cjs%2Fmbsmessage.js&min=1&sid=1631542832:2:11369), <anonymous>:3:9)
    at eval (<anonymous>)
    at js.php?f=js%2Fjquery-1.7.2.min.js%2Cjs%2Fmodernizr.custom.02358.js%2Cfunctions.js.php%2Cjs%2Fsite-functions.js%2Cform-validation.js.php%2Cform-validation-lang.php%2Cjs%2Fjquery-ui.min.js%2Cfacebox%2Ffacebox.js%2Cjs%2Fmbsmessage.js&min=1&sid=1631542832:2:11369
    at Function.globalEval (js.php?f=js%2Fjquery-1.7.2.min.js%2Cjs%2Fmodernizr.custom.02358.js%2Cfunctions.js.php%2Cjs%2Fsite-functions.js%2Cform-validation.js.php%2Cform-validation-lang.php%2Cjs%2Fjquery-ui.min.js%2Cfacebox%2Ffacebox.js%2Cjs%2Fmbsmessage.js&min=1&sid=1631542832:2:11380)
    at HTMLScriptElement.<anonymous> (js.php?f=js%2Fjquery-1.7.2.min.js%2Cjs%2Fmodernizr.custom.02358.js%2Cfunctions.js.php%2Cjs%2Fsite-functions.js%2Cform-validation.js.php%2Cform-validation-lang.php%2Cjs%2Fjquery-ui.min.js%2Cfacebox%2Ffacebox.js%2Cjs%2Fmbsmessage.js&min=1&sid=1631542832:4:2538)
    at Function.each (js.php?f=js%2Fjquery-1.7.2.min.js%2Cjs%2Fmodernizr.custom.02358.js%2Cfunctions.js.php%2Cjs%2Fsite-functions.js%2Cform-validation.js.php%2Cform-validation-lang.php%2Cjs%2Fjquery-ui.min.js%2Cfacebox%2Ffacebox.js%2Cjs%2Fmbsmessage.js&min=1&sid=1631542832:2:11776)
    at init.domManip (js.php?f=js%2Fjquery-1.7.2.min.js%2Cjs%2Fmodernizr.custom.02358.js%2Cfunctions.js.php%2Cjs%2Fsite-functions.js%2Cform-validation.js.php%2Cform-validation-lang.php%2Cjs%2Fjquery-ui.min.js%2Cfacebox%2Ffacebox.js%2Cjs%2Fmbsmessage.js&min=1&sid=1631542832:4:2441)
    at init.append (js.php?f=js%2Fjquery-1.7.2.min.js%2Cjs%2Fmodernizr.custom.02358.js%2Cfunctions.js.php%2Cjs%2Fsite-functions.js%2Cform-validation.js.php%2Cform-validation-lang.php%2Cjs%2Fjquery-ui.min.js%2Cfacebox%2Ffacebox.js%2Cjs%2Fmbsmessage.js&min=1&sid=1631542832:3:32408)
    at init.<anonymous> (js.php?f=js%2Fjquery-1.7.2.min.js%2Cjs%2Fmodernizr.custom.02358.js%2Cfunctions.js.php%2Cjs%2Fsite-functions.js%2Cform-validation.js.php%2Cform-validation-lang.php%2Cjs%2Fjquery-ui.min.js%2Cfacebox%2Ffacebox.js%2Cjs%2Fmbsmessage.js&min=1&sid=1631542832:4:1283)
    at Function.access (js.php?f=js%2Fjquery-1.7.2.min.js%2Cjs%2Fmodernizr.custom.02358.js%2Cfunctions.js.php%2Cjs%2Fsite-functions.js%2Cform-validation.js.php%2Cform-validation-lang.php%2Cjs%2Fjquery-ui.min.js%2Cfacebox%2Ffacebox.js%2Cjs%2Fmbsmessage.js&min=1&sid=1631542832:2:13266)
```

The error is related to the script which is called in TESTS.php :

```
 <script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=test&currency=USD" data-namespace="paypal_sdk"></script>
```

It seems the file is not imported or there is some errors in php file which I am not able to find it out. Can anyone help me with this please as I have spent my whole day on it. Thanks.

**EDIT :**
I have seperated the codes like below in order to prevent the preloading the papyal.button codes first. And now it looks like below :

```
<? 
require_once 'application-top.php';
require_once 'includes/navigation-functions.php';
require_once 'includes/site-functions-extended.php';
require_once 'includes/buy-deal-functions.php';
?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=AQgUM6x3URK1A-rcNIq56covuc0CYGv3pb5sYeL6-cqsO1HYV2CV6h4ur6BCly_1YYd3-UOMTNGtwQXd&currency=USD"></script>

<?
// ini_set('display_errors', 1);
// ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
// error_reporting(E_ALL);
$post = getPostedData();
print_r($post);
if ($_POST['mode'] == 'paypall')
{ 
    ?>   
    <script src="https://example.com/TESTS.js"></script>
<?
} 
?>
```

Now I am getting the error like below :

```
GET https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=AQgUM6x3URK1A-rcNIq56covuc0CYGv3pb5sYeL6-cqsO1HYV2CV6h4ur6BCly_1YYd3-UOMTNGtwQXd&currency=USD&_=1647908135353 net::ERR_ABORTED 400
```

When I checked the error code the requested src url is looking like different as it adds the timestamp at the end of the link therefore I am getting the error :

```
https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=AQgUM6x3URK1A-rcNIq56covuc0CYGv3pb5sYeL6-cqsO1HYV2CV6h4ur6BCly_1YYd3-UOMTNGtwQXd&currency=USD&_=1647908731335
```

**EDIT 2:**

The payment page looks like below :

[image]

Comment: PHP5.4 has been EOL for over 6 years! you should upgrade to php7.4 or higher and check if it's still happening

Comment: I am in php 7.3 though

Comment: Don't try and inject an entire HTML document into an existing element

Comment: but how can I separate the file ? I mean what is the problem including html document? Can you please explain a bi more? I have deleted all the html parts and tried like that but result is the same.

Comment: try `paypal.Buttons({` instead of `paypal_sdk.Buttons({`

Comment: Yeah I have already tried that but not helped unfortunately. Same result...

Comment: Most probably the error is popping up because the `https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js` is still loading when your `paypal_sdk.Buttons({` code is trying to execute. This should be because your are trying to inject the whole document.
 Try to separate the code.

Comment: @Dula, I have tried what you said and now I am getting the following error : `GET https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=AQgUM6x3URK1A-rcNIq56covuc0CYGv3pb5sYeL6-cqsO1HYV2CV6h4ur6BCly_1YYd3-UOMTNGtwQXd&currency=USD&_=1647907770202 net::ERR_ABORTED 400`

Comment: hmm..can you show the updated code?

Comment: @Dula, Please see the first post, I have edited the post and added the part you mention.

Comment: Where is `&_=1647907770202` coming from? Never seen that before. Is your browser adding it somehow? Try with a different browser. Or is it being added by your server-side page processing, somehow? It looks like a hacky way to disable cache, but `_` is not a valid param to the SDK and you need to disable this from being sent. Won't work with it.

Comment: Absolutely have no idea where it comes from. I don't have any parameters like that in my side. It seems server side is asking for that URL but it shouldn’t, because it won’t work with that. Tried with different browsers and result is the same.

Comment: In all scenarios I am getting an error about the `paypal is not defined` and then another one `GET https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=AQgUM6x3URK1A-rcNIq56covuc0CYGv3pb5sYeL6-cqsO1HYV2CV6h4ur6BCly_1YYd3-UOMTNGtwQXd&currency=USD&_=1647907770202 net::ERR_ABORTED 400`

Comment: you're on 7.3? but the `<? ` opening tag hasn't been accepted since php5.4 ..? since php5.6 you need `<?=` or `<?php` (there's also a 3rd option but it was horrible and removed in 7.0, won't mention it)

Comment: I'm in my vps and I can turn it short tags on, that's not a problem at all.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to inject the whole page. You can do something like this.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <!-- Add meta tags for mobile and IE -->
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <title> PayPal Checkout Integration | Client Demo </title>
        <script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=test&currency=USD" data-namespace="paypal_sdk"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
<!-- Set up a container element for the button -->
<div id="paypal-button-container"></div>
<!-- Include the PayPal JavaScript SDK -->

<?php if($_POST['mode'] == 'paypall') { ?>
<script>
    // Render the PayPal button into #paypal-button-container
    paypal_sdk.Buttons({
        // Set up the transaction
        createOrder: function(data, actions) {
            return actions.order.create({
                purchase_units: [{
                    amount: {
                        value: '88.44'
                    }
                }]
            });
        },
        // Finalize the transaction
        onApprove: function(data, actions) {
            return actions.order.capture().then(function(orderData) {
                // Successful capture! For demo purposes:
                console.log('Capture result', orderData, JSON.stringify(orderData, null, 2));
                var transaction = orderData.purchase_units[0].payments.captures[0];
                alert('Transaction '+ transaction.status + ': ' + transaction.id + '\n\nSee console for all available details');

                // Replace the above to show a success message within this page, e.g.
                // const element = document.getElementById('paypal-button-container');
                // element.innerHTML = '';
                // element.innerHTML = '<h3>Thank you for your payment!</h3>';
                // Or go to another URL:  actions.redirect('thank_you.html');
            });
        }
    }).render('#paypal-button-container');
</script>
<?php } ?>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply, the problem is that I must use ajax due to the structure of the website. And if I use the ajax with your edition I am getting the exactly same error : `Uncaught ReferenceError: paypal_sdk is not defined`. I am not getting any error if I use the file as a html and access directly to it.

Comment: Are you loading this inside an iframe??

Comment: Not actually, I am calling redirectpaypal function from a file which is called `buy-deal-ajax.php` which looks like this : 
`while ($row = $rs->fetch_assoc()) {
                switch ($row["po_name"]) {
                    case "PayPal":
                        echo "<li><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="redirectPaypal();" rel="tabs2"><span class="largetxt">t_lang('M_TXT_PAYPAL') . "</span> .............` .

Comment: yes, but the does the buttons displayed inside a popup modal or an iframe?

Comment: Not iframe, nor modal popup. I only use ajax and pure CSS. Please check my first post to see how the website looks like.

Comment: oh..got it. you are using a tab. Why don't you load the buttons when the payment page loads and display the contents when the tab is clicked?

Comment: I have tried to add it to the `buy-deal-ajax.php`  but the getting the exact same error : `GET https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=AQgUM6x3URK1A-rcNIq56covuc0CYGv3pb5sYeL6-cqsO1HYV2CV6h4ur6BCly_1YYd3-UOMTNGtwQXd&currency=USD&_=1647907770202 net::ERR_ABORTED 400`

I mean the functions are preloaded and once I press paypal it shows me the same reference error.

Comment: I mean the functions are preloaded and once I press PayPal it shows me the same reference error. Actually it is still ajax, so unless I press the button "PayPal" it doesn't load the JS codes.

Comment: In all scenarios I am getting an error about the `paypal is not defined` and then another one : `GET https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=AQgUM6x3URK1A-rcNIq56covuc0CYGv3pb5sYeL6-cqsO1HYV2CV6h4ur6BCly_1YYd3-UOMTNGtwQXd&currency=USD&_=1647907770202 net::ERR_ABORTED 400`

Answer (score 0):

Anyone who is struggling with this case just use the code like below :

```
function loadAsync(url, callback) {
  var s = document.createElement('script');
  s.setAttribute('src', url); s.onload = callback;
  document.head.insertBefore(s, document.head.firstElementChild);
}

// Usage -- callback is inlined here, but could be a named function

loadAsync('https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=test&currency=USD', function() {
  paypal.Buttons({

    // Set up the transaction
    createOrder: function(data, actions) {
        return actions.order.create({
            purchase_units: [{
                amount: {
                    value: '0.01'
                }
            }]
        });
    },

    // Finalize the transaction
    onApprove: function(data, actions) {
        return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {
           //...
        });
    }

  }).render('#paypal-button-container');
});
```

Loading a script that way is asynchronous and takes time therefore the event `onload` must be used as callback.